# CommonJs and AMD are both kind of dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, amd, commonjs

I just touch the concept of `dependency injection`,

and then I think the CommonJs and AMD are kind of `dependency injection`.

Because when define a module under either standard, you have to load its dependent module  first.

The module you defined, should expose abstract API only, less detail possible

Am I right? Does I miss something?

Comment: RequireJS has dependency injection and inversion of control out of the box. As far as I understand it, RequireJS is an IoC container itself.

Answer (score 1):

It could be used as such with some work but isn't really.

Dependency injection is usually about compiled code. In most cases, changing a referenced binary requires recompilation and redeployment. What [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection) allows is the selection of which binary to use at runtime via a text file thus eliminating the need to recompile the product.

With [amd](/questions/tagged/amd) via libraries like [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs), the pattern you tend to see is straight referencing via convention, which feels a lot like a **project reference**.

For [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)-dependent projects, you do start to see library swaps via config. In this case, the path to the reference is updated by changing code. While this feels similar to [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection), it is a **code change**. For example, the following defines a path to [modernizr](/questions/tagged/modernizr) in [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs)

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        modernizr: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min'
    }
});
```

To *change* the dependency, the developer would need to *change* **code not config**.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it like this:

AMD is to JavaScript what:

- `#include` is to C
- `import` is to Java
- `require` is to NodeJS

Indeed it can be used to inject dependencies but when thought of as a DI mechanism -- instead of just a module loader -- it encourages writing every module as a Singleton.

Example:

```
define('a', function () {
  return {
    doX: function () { ... }
  };
});

define('b', ['a'],  function (a) {
  return {
    doY: function () { 
      a.doX(); 
    }
  };
});
```

You could say that you're injecting `a` into `b` but since there's only one copy of `a` -- a Singleton -- that AMD knows about it will always use the same every time a module uses it as a dependency.

If you instead do:

```
define('A', function () {
  function A(options) {  // some constructor/factory method
     return {
       doX: function () {...}
     }
  }

  return A;
});

define('b', ['A'],  function (A) {

    if (<some condition>) {
      var customOptions = {<some options>}
      var a1 = new A(customOptions);

      return {
         doY: function () {
            a1.doX();
         }
      };
    }

    var defaultOptions = {<default>}
    var a2 = new A(defaultOptions);
    return {
      doY: function () {
         a2.doY();
      }
    }
});
```

In this second example, you have the ability to create multiple instances of module A since it returns a constructor/factory method instead of an instance.

In order to facilitate testing avoiding Singletons is usually a good idea since it means you can actually inject different instances or even stubs. This becomes almost impossible if the module you're trying to inject is a Singleton.